# How do I leverage generics and check my parameters in this usage of addItem?

Tags: java, generics

So I'm getting the good ol' `unchecked call to addItem(E)` for a JComboBox.  I'm familiar with the common case, but the combobox is in a list processed functionally though and the solution eludes me.  Stripped down code sample:

```
public static Boolean final test(final List<JComboBox> comboboxList) {
  final List<String> stuff=new ArrayList<>();
  // stuff gets stuffed with stuff here
  comboboxList.forEach((JComboBox combobox) -> {
    combobox.removeAllItems();
    stuff.forEach((contents) -> {
      combobox.addItem(contents);
    });
  });
}
```

The comboboxes in the List being passed in are all declared as `<String>`, but that doesn't seem to help the addItem in the forEach.  Seems like I should declare it in the forEach, but I've been unable to find a valid syntax for doing so.

Comment: You're using a raw type `JComboBox`, so you'll always get that warning. Should it be `List<JComboBox<String>>`?

Comment: Ah, was not aware diamonds could be nested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The comboboxes in the List being passed in are all declared as
>   , but that doesn't seem to help the addItem in the forEach.

It doesn't help because you don't specify the `String` type at each time you declare a variable with the `JComboBox` class.
So it declares raw `JComboBox` , that is `JComboBox<Object>`.
Whereas the warnings.

```
public static Boolean test(final List<JComboBox<String>> comboboxList) {
    final List<String> stuff = new ArrayList<>();
    // stuff gets stuffed with stuff here
    comboboxList.forEach((JComboBox<String> combobox) -> {
        combobox.removeAllItems();
        stuff.forEach((contents) -> {
            combobox.addItem(contents);
        });
    });

   return someBooleanValue; // to compile
}
```

Note that declaring the type of the lambda parameter is not mandatory. You could shortcut your code in this way :

```
public static Boolean test(final List<JComboBox<String>> comboboxList) {
    final List<String> stuff = new ArrayList<>();
    // stuff gets stuffed with stuff here
    comboboxList.forEach(combobox -> {
        combobox.removeAllItems();
        stuff.forEach(combobox::addItem);
    });

   return someBooleanValue; // to compile
}
```